# HTML Agility Pack can't find xPath

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm writing a web scraping program in C# using HTML Agility Pack. I previously had this written in Java but I am moving it to C#. Before I was using jSoup to parse my HTML and had no issues getting the elements via xpath from Yahoo Finance, but now, with HTML Agility Pack, I can't get any element from this site using the xpaths, and they seem to be legitimate nodes. Here is an example

http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AMZN is the site

I use this code to add it to a spreadsheet

```
ws.get_Range("A2").Value2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='table1']/tbody/tr[1]/td").InnerText;
```

I should add that this is an Excel add-in. When I write the HTML to the spreadsheet I can't seem to find "table1" anywhere in the HTML, but I can find it when I print the HTML to a text file. Any insight on finding these nodes?

Answer (score 3):

I found it. HtmlAgilityPack does not like to use the "/tbody" part of an xpath. Take that out if you are searching through table elements.

Answer (score -1):

***Catch the difference in Xpath***

//*[@id="quote-summary"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span  **Data1**

//*[@id="quote-summary"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span  **Data2**